# Are apple trees "loaded" or "laden" with fruit?

Tags: word-choice, differences

> Laden
>
> - [adj.  having or carrying a large amount of something](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/laden)
>
> Loaded
>
> - [adj. filled with a great quantity](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/loaded)

Are fruit-trees laden or loaded with fruit?

Comment: Why do you think your question is not answered by the other question you cite?  To me, it is.

Comment: You should attribute your quotes. [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/loaded) gives the participial adjective usage of 'loaded': **loaded** adjective  full
1 carrying a load; full and heavy.
synonym: laden
_a fully loaded truck_ // which shows that for this sense, 'laden' and 'loaded' are usually interchangeable. However, where only a verb form works, 'loaded' (_the gun was being loaded_ / _she loaded the gun_) alone is possible. Also, dice etc can't be 'laden', so even the adjectives aren't always interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, apple trees can be laden with fruit, in which case they are loaded with fruit. And vice versa.